# IntelliJ - Failed to start: 0 passed, 1 not started

Tags: java, unit-testing, ide, intellij-idea

Just been playing around for the first time with IntelliJ IDEA Community edition, first time I have worked with it so if I'm missing something, please excuse me.

I have a bunch of unit tests which I run, however, when running them in IntelliJ (with the standard setup out of the box), I intermittently get the following error in the console:

> 03:14:17 Failed to start: 58 passed, 1 not started

I have searched the web but to no avail.  If I run just the test that failed, it may or may not print out a similar error:

> 03:19:54 Failed to start: 0 passed, 1 not started

If I keep trying, eventually it works and tells me that all of my tests have passed.

The image is not the error as an exclamation mark, it is a different error icon ([image: error icon]), which I do not recognise.  The error in Event Log window appears as red text.

It always appears to happen with only one test and it is always the same test for any given set of tests. I.E. In a different project, the same issue also appears, but for a different test (but it's always the same one in each project or set of tests).

One more thing to note is that this ONLY happens when debugging and not when running, so it may be something to do with connecting the debugger?

It all works perfectly fine with Eclipse.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Is this test marked red, as in failed, or is it displayed differently?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @sebi.  I have updated the question to include the image.

Comment: Looks like a bug, you can submit it at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA and attach the sample project with the steps to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder.  You are right, it does look like a bug.  I cant seem to reproduce a simple sample project to simulate the issue.  Unfortunately, I also can not post my entire project source so in a bit of a pickle.  I will post all the info I can.

Comment: Same story. "Failed to start: 0 passed, 1 not started". idea 17.3.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the same error. It was something weird sent to `System.out` that made IntellJ IDEA test "not started".

Comment: Had same issue, 
it was a System.out.printf in some part of the code that was used and called by my test, so be carefull on it.

Answer (score 15):

The issue for me is **Failed to start: 1, passed: 0** . I'm using Spring Boot 2.4.0 with Junit5 to test the Controller Class. I just commented out the version tag in the junit-jupiter-engine dependency. Then it worked. Really strange. It might helpful for someone.

Comment: fixed it for me instantly. spent a day trying to figure this out. everything kept telling me to add different items to pom and none of it worked. simply removing the version tag had it all working. This worked a few months ago and randomly stopped. Seems a new dependency fails with certain versions of jupiter

Comment: I had multiple versions of `junit-jupiter-engine` in my pom that was causing this.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175006) for IntelliJ IDEA, you can vote for it if you still encounter this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes similar error happens with scala code when you mix sclamock's `MockFactory` with scalatest's `AsyncFlatSpec`.

So, be sure to use `AsyncMockFactory` like below.

```
class ExampleSpec extends AsyncFlatSpec with AsyncMockFactory
```

Comment: Oh man I lost 3 hours on this, thank you good sir :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem was in pom.
I moved from fulling working application to spring-boot implementation and only imported spring-boot-starter-test in dependency for testing.

I solved by excluding junit part from spring-boot-starter-test and added junit dependency of latest version in separate block.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this may have been a bug on IntelliJ, it has been raised with them.

Comment: Any idea if it's been fixed?

Comment: If it is a bug, it still exists now. The length that this issue has persisted makes me think that it isn't a bug

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem (in Android Studio but its a customised IntelliJ) and the reason was WHERE the cursor was when I ran tests using CTRL-SHIFT-F10.

```
@Parameterized.Parameters
public static Collection data()
```

Once I moved the cursor into a test method or not inside any method, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Whatever be the number of `scenarios`, it was showing 1 extra `scenario` in `NOT STARTED` stage. I was using Scenario Outline to run tests and had commented the rows in the `Example tables`.

I later found out that **commenting the whole example table** (which I didn't wanted to run) resolved the issue rather than commenting each row.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that cracked me up a little in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1. The test case ran without any recognizable errors or irregularities, but in the end JUnit claimed the case as not started.

Figured out it was caused by trying to print into a PrintWriter that has already been closed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to **mock** a class having a **public static method**. Problem solved when everything is set free from static context.

Answer (score 0):

I came along not started tests, when attempting to test code that called `System.exit(1)` . IntelliJ would not start my tests until I removed the exiting behavior like this:

At first I replaced all direct lines in the code from

```
System.exit(1)
```

to

```
onFailure.run();
```

with

```
unnable onFailure = () -> System.exit(1);
```

in the code itself. In the Test-Code I replaced the Runnable with a testable mock Runnable

```
  Runnable mockOnFailure =
      () -> {
        throw new CustomError(
            "Some descriptive message here.");
      };
```

and than I expected that Error to be thrown like so (using AssertJ for nice assertion statements)

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThatExceptionOfType;


  assertThatExceptionOfType(CustomError.class).isThrownBy(
      () -> {
        callingCodeThatCallsOnFailure();
      }
  );
```

Now the tests are all being startet by the IDE as desired.

Feel free to reuse that if it is of help to you. I do not claim any ownership or copyright to any of those lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was mixing AsyncMockFactory with AnyWordSpecLike, which caused all my tests to be silently skipped.  Changing to AsyncWordSpecLike solved it.

Apparently there's a fix for this that causes the code to fail to compile if you mix them incorrectly, but it hasn't made it into a ScalaMock release as of today:

https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/pull/451