# IntelliJ: Tests not started

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit

I'm running a lot of JUnit tests in parallel, and I frequently get results along the lines of
"N tests passed, M tests failed, P tests not started" (in contrast to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166283/intellij-failed-to-start-0-passed-1-not-started), where no tests start at all).

What can cause this? I tried the "invalidate cache" option, however, this does not appear to solve anything. I should mention that tests take a while longer to run than the average JUnit tests (they can take up to 90 seconds to run), could this have anything to do with it? Right now I simply press "rerun failed tests" until I have forced IntelliJ do run all of them, which is rather cumbersome. I'm not sending anything weird to System.out either, and as I've stated I do get them to run eventually.

**It runs tests for about ten minutes, and then no further tests are started. Is there a timeout of some kind somewhere that I can't find?**

Sometimes this appears in the console after this happens:

```
Process finished with exit code 255
```

Version details:

- IntelliJ version 13.1.4
- JUnit 4.10

Comment: Is it the same tests that are started each time? No problems with synchronization / threads / dependency injection?

Comment: None of the sort - each test is completely separate and the tests do not share anything at all.

Comment: Ok. same ones not starting each time, or does it vary?

Comment: The problem seems to be a 10 minute limit somewhere. As I stated in the post, I can get them *all* to run eventually as long as I constantly hit "rerun failed tests" every time it happens. And they always run in the same order.

Comment: @vikingsteve: it will vary on how long the previous tests take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a timeout option for the `@Test` annotation - have you tried increasing that?

And there is also a `@Rule` and `Timeout` option.

Info [about Timeout for Tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Timeout-for-tests) - I hope it is relevant?

Comment: I am not using the mentioned annotation at all. Besides, if I read that page correctly, it should make tests fail rather than not getting started in the first place. And the timeout is always tied to a single test and not a series of tests (even though they are in the same class - doing the globalTimeout @Rule mentioned will still set a limit *per test*).

Comment: Are you using the default test runner, or a different one? e.g. junit test runner or spring test runner.

Comment: The default one in IntelliJ.

Comment: Try @RunWith a different test runner? http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/RunWith.html

Comment: Turns out I did have a different test runner after all. Facepalm. Thanks.

Comment: ;) glad our discussion got there in the end

Comment: @ChristianJonassen, can you please elaborate further?  I am running into the same problem running a set of tests for a module in IntelliJ 2016.1.  What test runner did you have, and what did you switch to?  Mine seems to be using `com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter`, which is what is selected by the IDE automatically.

Comment: I used a custom made one that had a timeout configured. You can try searching in relevant code for @Test(timeout or something along those lines.

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was due to a silly mistake, I did not add a static keyword on the method annotated with `@BeforeAll`.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem.
Solved by adding test platform in build.gradle.

```
test {
useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Restart intelij by removing all modules and adding them again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I resolved this issue by fixing some dependencies issue.

In my root pom.xml, I added this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and in my module, I added this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and removed the old one:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
  <version>RELEASE</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I fix this problem just changing
webdrivermanager version 5.4.0 that it is

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```